# How to add an extra field value when facing unique value exists on Solr?

Tags: solr

Below is a part of my configuration file:

```
<fields>
        <field name="neoId" stored="true" type="sint" indexed="true" required="true" />
        <field name="skillString" stored="true" type="string" indexed="true" required="true" />
        <field name="skillName" stored="true" type="text" indexed="true" required="true" />


      </fields>

      <uniqueKey>skillString</uniqueKey>
      <defaultSearchField>skillName</defaultSearchField>
```

When adding a new document, if skillString exists, it does not add the document. That's good. But the document's neoId field might be different than the one on the index. So I'd like to add an extra neoId to the document on the index when a skillString already exists. Is there a way to do that? Because I wasn't able to find a way. I thought that first checking if it exists, than add document or update document accordingly; but I'd like to do that in a single query since it will be inside a huge (40k) loop and be running constantly.

Answer (score 0):

Since skillString is your unique key when you add a new document and the unique key is the same Solr will **OVERRIDE** your whole document (ie. all the fields).
Solr does not have a proper update operation so every time it delete and re-insert the document.

So if you just update the document Solr should automatically take care of your requirement.